# Custom Error Response Handling with Moya + RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, objectmapper, moya

I'm using Moya with RxSwift for networking in an iOS app, and I'd like to be able to consume my API's custom error responses when my `Observer`s get calls to `onError`.

The API always returns error responses in the following JSON format:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error message goes here",
      "code": "String error code"
   }
}
```

**The goal is to achieve something similar to the following code snippet, where the error passed in `onError` is my custom error type instead of the `Moya.Error` type:**

```
observable
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { response in
            // Do typical onNext stuff
        },
        onError: { error in
            // Get and consume my custom error type here:
            let customError = error as! MyCustomErrorModel
            print("My API's error message: \(customError.error?.message)")
            print("My API's error code: \(customError.error?.code)")
        })
```

I'm able to successfully intercept and deserialize these errors into my custom error model using a custom `PluginType` (pasted below, from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706689/how-to-handle-the-response-of-all-types-of-requests-in-one-handler-but-also-uni)), but I do not know how to finally pass these models along to the `Observer`.

```
import Foundation
import Moya
import ObjectMapper
import Result

struct CustomAPIErrorPlugin: PluginType {

// Called immediately before a request is sent over the network (or stubbed).
func willSendRequest(request: RequestType, target: TargetType) { }

// Called after a response has been received, but before the MoyaProvider has invoked its completion handler.
func didReceiveResponse(result: Result<Moya.Response, Moya.Error>, target: TargetType) {
    let responseJSON: AnyObject
    if let response = result.value {
        do {
            responseJSON = try response.mapJSON()
            if let errorResponse = Mapper<MyCustomErrorModel>().map(responseJSON) {
                print("Custom error code from server: \(errorResponse.error?.code)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failure to parse JSON response")
        }
    } else {
        print("Network Error = \(result.error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to extend the ObservableType since that ends up being the cleanest solution when we talk about handling api error responses. Something as below (not tested ...)

```
extension ObservableType where E == Response {
  func filterSuccess() -> Observable<E> {
    return flatMap { (response) -> Observable<E> in
        if 200 ... 299 ~= response.statusCode {
            return Observable.just(response)
        }

        if let errorJson = response.data.toJson(), 
           let error = Mapper<MyCustomErrorModel>().map(errorJson) {
            return Observable.error(error)
        }

        // Its an error and can't decode error details from server, push generic message
        let genericError = MyCustomErrorModel.genericError(code: response.statusCode, message: "Unknown Error")
        return Observable.error(genericError)
    }
}
```

This is how you use it

```
provider.request(.test)
        .filterSuccess()
        .mapJSON()
        .subscribe { [unowned self] e in
            switch e {
            case .next(let json as JSON):
            case .error(let error as MyCustomErrorModel):
            // Handle your custom error here
            default: break
            }
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```